# Access a function inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a noob , and currently learning `reactjs` , can someone explain,how to access a function inside a `component` that resides inside another `component` in `reactjs` ?

example:

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(){
        console.log("handling click")
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        )
    }
}

// This component is in another file

import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne'

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.handleComp=this.handleComp.bind(this)
    }

    handleComp(){
        ComponentOne.handleClick() 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={this.handleComp}>Click me</button>
        )

    }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Do you mean access a function that belongs to a parent? Or to a function that belongs to a child? Or to a completely unrelated (i.e. not in the tree) component

Comment: Can you please be a bit more precise, and add some code to your question? :)

Comment: @patrick Can you give any link or example of all the three ways ?

Comment: how are you currently learning it? there should be a tutorial on this. Have you watched an entire series on react on youtube?

Comment: @nik7 in your example there is no commonality between the two components. Does componentTwo render componentOne? is there a parent rendering both of these?

Answer (score 3):

Generally when you are using react and you want to execute functions inside other components [**you use a ref**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).

I have had explicit use cases where I have a `VideoPlayer` component and I want to execute a play or pause function on the player (outside of the component) but I want the `VideoPlayer`'s play function to be called to update its state and everything else. It can be very powerful!

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.childComponentRef && this.childComponentRef.someFunc();
    } 
    assignChildComponentRef = target => this.childComponentRef = target;
    render() {
        retrurn (<div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>trigger child function click</button>
            <ChildComponent ref={this.assignChildComponentRef} prop1={this.something} />
        </div>);
    }
}

// child component implementation
class ChildComponent  extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: 0 };
    }
    someFunc = () => {
        this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.value}</div>
    }
}
```

Few things to notice here.

1. You will see a lot of examples using string refs. [**This is now considered a bad practice and will be removed in later versions.**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)
2. I would only use refs when absolutely needed. However, If you need to have a reference to your component a ref is the intended way to do that.